# Convertir resultados a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, opencv

vengo con otra duda con respecto a python, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para convertir a `DataFrame` los resultados de una operación que está dentro de un ciclo `for`?, es decir, realizo la formula para encontrar el área de círculos, todo en un ciclo `for` pero quiero que esos resultados convertirlos a `DataFrame`. No se si me di a entender, soy malo explicando mis ideas. El código es este:

```
def imgDetect(self):
    image = self.aux4
    _, contours, _ = cv.findContours(image, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    circles = [cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt) for cnt in contours]
    print("Circulos encontrados: ", len(circles), 'Tipo: ', type(circles))
    for i in range(len(circles)):
        radius = circles[i][1]
        area = pi * (radius * radius)
        area = area * self.Scal
        self.res = pd.DataFrame(area)
        print(self.res)
```

El error que me arroja con este código es el siguiente:

```
File "C:\Users\EdgKrg27\Desktop\Programas\Python\PIIC\proImagen.py", line 73, in imgDetect
    self.res = pd.DataFrame(area)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\PIIC\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 509, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Agradezco infinitamente su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, debes crear un DataFrame con todas las áreas, no uno por cada área. Es decir, debes  instanciar `pandas.DataFrame` fuera del ciclo `for` y no una vez en cada iteración.

Por otro lado , le estás pasando al inicializador un solo escalar (el área en esa iteración) y el inicializador de [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) espera como parámetro data un ndarray de NumPy, un iterable (tupla, lista, etc), un diccionario o otro DataFrame.

Yo suelos usar un diccionario con los nombres de las columnas como claves y como valores los datos de esa columna.

Para generar tu DataFrame con una sola columna ("Area") puedes usar una expresión generadora y así evitar tener que crear un contenedor intermedio para almacenar los valores mientras iteras:

```
def imgDetect(self):
    image = self.aux4
    _, contours, _ = cv.findContours(image, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    circles = [cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt) for cnt in contours]
    print(f"Circulos encontrados: {len(circles)}, Tipo: {type(circles)}")
    areas_gen = (pi * (radius * radius) * self.Scal for _, radius in circles)
    self.res = pd.DataFrame({"Area": areas_gen})
    print(self.res)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla, me ayudaste mucho, =)